# Visual Studio Code Snippets - Using a number over 9 for a placeholder?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Whenever I make a snippet using `${#:Default}`, if the `#` is over 9 then it will mess up the tabbing.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is this a limitation to the snippet placeholders?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so. I solved this quickly. I considered deleting this but I had difficulty getting clarification so this example may help someone.

Doing the following will tab to any 3# before moving on.

```
"Create a Timeline Event" : {
    "prefix": "event_timeline",
    "body":
    [
        "- Title: ${1:Title}",
        "  Description: ${2:description.}",
        "  EventDate:",
        "    Year: ${30:Year}",
        "    Month: ${31:Month}",
        "    Day: ${32:Day}",
        "    Hour: ${33:Hour}",
        "    Minute: ${34:Minute}",
        "${4:TimelineEntry}"
    ],
    "description": "Creates a timeline event for the DnD timeline"
}
```

Check [these](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_placeholders) docs out. It does show `[0-9]+` for the ints, so maybe this is intended.